# "OK google" via external bluetooth button

Tags: android, google-search

Here is what I'd like to do - I'd like to have a bluetooth dongle with a button that when pressed, takes my phone out of whatever state it is in and starts google voice search. That is, if the phone is off (screen off) it will turn on (assume no PIN/pattern lock). Then, it will start google voice search just as if I was to pronounce "OK google". The way I was thinking of solving this was to have the BT dongle show up as either BT keyboard or BT hands free, and send the right code to the Android phone to trigger the operation. I could not, however, find such code. The next tier solution is to have some listener app running in the background, listening the BT keyboard codes, and triggering google search via some intent.
Any comments to put me on the right track here?
Thanks.